# Comunicación mediante Puerto Serial C#

Tags: c#, serialport, modbus

Hola tengo el siguiente problema, estoy desarrollando una aplicación de escritorio basada en C#, necesito comunicarme con un transmisor de peso, el problema es que no sé como comunicarme con el transmisor, según el manual utiliza el protocolo Modbus RTU, como muestro en el código, le envío información mediante un arreglo de bytes utilizando el SerialPort, parece funcionar, pero a la hora de recibir información no me interpreta correctamente el programa o no recibe nada, no se si el evento handler esta mal ubicado o mal programado, por favor, requiero de orientación en el tema, ya sea para enviar correctamente información e igualmente recibir utilizando C# y Modbus Rtu. Cabe mencionar que la conexión es mediante RS485

`````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

namespace Comunicacion_con_Balanza
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SerialPort SPpuertos = new SerialPort();
        private delegate void DelegadoAcceso(string accion);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SPpuertos.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(spDatosRecibidos);

        }

        private void btnBuscarPuertos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] PuertosDisponibles = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            cboPuertos.Items.Clear();
            foreach (string puertoSimple in PuertosDisponibles)
            {
                cboPuertos.Items.Add(puertoSimple);
            }

            if (cboPuertos.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                cboPuertos.SelectedIndex = 0;
                MessageBox.Show("Seleccione Puerto");
                btnConectar.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No se han detectado puertos");
                cboPuertos.Items.Clear();
                cboPuertos.Text = "                    ";
                btnConectar.Enabled = false;
                btnEnviarDatos.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void btnConectar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (btnConectar.Text.Equals("CONECTAR"))
                {
                    SPpuertos.BaudRate = Int32.Parse(cboBaudRate.Text);
                    SPpuertos.DataBits = 8;
                    SPpuertos.Parity = Parity.None;
                    SPpuertos.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                    SPpuertos.Handshake = Handshake.None;
                    SPpuertos.PortName = cboPuertos.Text;
                    SPpuertos.ReadTimeout = 500;
                    SPpuertos.WriteTimeout = 500;

                    try
                    {
                        SPpuertos.Open();
                        btnConectar.Text = "DESCONECTAR";
                        btnEnviarDatos.Enabled = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                else if (btnConectar.Text == "DESCONECTAR")
                {
                    SPpuertos.Close();
                    btnConectar.Text = "CONECTAR";
                    btnEnviarDatos.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void spDatosRecibidos(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Enabled == true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                var data = SPpuertos.ReadExisting();
                this.BeginInvoke(new DelegadoAcceso(RecibirDatos), new object[] { data });
            }
        }

        private void RecibirDatos(string accion)
        {
            txtRecibirDatos.Text = accion;
        }

        private void btnEnviarDatos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (SPpuertos.IsOpen)
            {
                if (txtEnviarDatos.Text.Equals("PESO"))
                {
                    Byte[] Buffer_out_single8 = new Byte[8];
                    Buffer_out_single8[0] = 0x08;
                    Buffer_out_single8[1] = 0x04;
                    Buffer_out_single8[2] = 0x00;
                    Buffer_out_single8[3] = 0x04;
                    Buffer_out_single8[4] = 0x00;
                    Buffer_out_single8[5] = 0x01;
                    byte[] crc8 = CalculaCRC(Buffer_out_single8);
                    Buffer_out_single8[6] = crc8[0];
                    Buffer_out_single8[7] = crc8[1];
                    SPpuertos.Write(Buffer_out_single8, 0, Buffer_out_single8.Length);
                    //SPpuertos.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    string texto = txtEnviarDatos.Text;
                    SPpuertos.Write(texto.Trim());
                    txtRecibirDatos.Text = SPpuertos.ReadExisting();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Puerto Cerrado");
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SPpuertos.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(spDatosRecibidos);
        }

        private static byte[] CalculaCRC(byte[] datos)
        {
            byte[] checkSum = new byte[2];
            ushort reg_crc = 0XFFFF;
            for (int i = 0; i < datos.Length - 2; i++)
            {
                reg_crc ^= datos[i];
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                {
                    if ((reg_crc & 0x01) == 1)
                    {
                        reg_crc = (ushort)((reg_crc >> 1) ^ 0xA001);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        reg_crc = (ushort)(reg_crc >> 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            checkSum[1] = (byte)((reg_crc >> 8) & 0xFF);
            checkSum[0] = (byte)(reg_crc & 0xFF);
            return checkSum;
        }
    }
}````
`````

Comment: Sugiero que compruebes primero con una herramienta de test de ModBus que la comunicación funciona correctamente (ModBusPoll por ejemplo). Después comprueba que la trama coincide con la que estás generando. El problema puede estar en muchos sitios, desde una cuestión eléctrica de cableado, pasando por la configuración del puerto, el direccionamiento ModBus, la construcción del CRC...

Comment: Leer el puerto con ReadExisting, que devuelve una cadena de texto, no es adecuado. Mejor usa BytesToRead y Read.

Comment: muchas gracias, consulta, en código, como sería apropiado usar los métodos BytesToRead y Read?

Comment: var btr = p.BytesToRead;     
if ( btr > 0 ) {
     byte []data = new byte[ btr ];
     p.Read( buffer, 0, btr );
}

Comment: Así obtienes los bytes que te enviará el dispositivo ModBus, que no son una cadena de texto,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quizas ya has resuelto tu problema, pero igual te envio info.
en tu rutina de envio de datos la trama que estas enviando es incorrecta la siguiente
tabla espero te sea util.

; ************ TRAMA FUNCIONES  DESDE MASTER **********************************
; FUNCION 2 DIR_ESCLAVO - FUNC - REGH - REGL - BITH - BITL -HCRC - LOWCRC
; FUNCION 3 DIR_ESCLAVO - FUNC - REGH - REGL - DATAH - DATAL - CRCH - CRCL
; FUNCION 6 DIR_ESCLAVO - FUNC - REGH - REGL - DATAH - DATAL - CRCH - CRCL
; LONGITUD DE LA TRAMA 8 BYTE
;*******************************************************************************
; FUNCION 16 DIR_ESCLAVO - FUNC - REGH - REGL - CNT_REGH - CNT_REGL - CNT_BYTES - DATAH - DATAL - CRCH - CRCL
; LONGITUD  MINIMA DE LA TRAMA 11 BYTE
;******************************************************************************
; ************ TRAMA FUNCIONES  DESDE ESCLAVO *********************************
; FUNCION 2 DIR_ESCLAVO - FUNC - REGH - REGL - BITH - BITL -HCRC - LOWCRC
; FUNCION 3 DIR_ESCLAVO - FUNC - Nro.DATOS - DATO1 - DATO2 - DATO3 - CRCH - CRCL
; FUNCION 6 DIR_ESCLAVO - FUNC - REGH - REGL - DATAH - DATAL - CRCH - CRCL
; FUNCION 16 DIR_ESCLAVO - FUNC - REGH - REGL - CNT_REGH - CNT_REGL - CRCH - CRCL
; LONGITUD DE LA TRAMA 8 BYTE

---

; ejemplo lectura funcion #3 : 1, 3, 0, 100, 0, 1, 197, 213
;ejemplo escritur funcion #6 : 1, 6, 0, 91, 0, 1, 57, 217.

---

;ejemplo escritura funcion #16 20 registros :
;valor byte crc_LOW, crc_HIGH: 239,183
longitud trama modbus (byte): 47
trama modbus mas crc: 1,16,0,94,0,20,40,0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,7,0,8,0,9,0,10,0,11,0,12,0,13,0,14,0,15,0,16,0,17,0,18,0,19,0,20,239,183

utiliza un for para el envio por puerto serial y para la recepcion como ya te han dicho readbytes y lo guardas en un bufer. el soft que uso modscan y modsim.
disculpa lo largo de la respuesta y espero te sea de utilidad.

saludos

luis lopez